# Apache Spark not recognising import from external Jar

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to adapt some code from Apache Zeppelin for a personal project.  The idea is to pass Scala source code to be executed in Spark.  Everything is working fine, until when I try to use an external jar. For this, I call

```
SparkConf#setJars(externalJars);
```

And I can see in the logs that my jar was added:

```
Added JAR file:/Users/.../lsa.jar at spark://192.168.0.16:60376/jars/lsa.jar with timestamp 1470532825125
```

And when I check the UI of Spark `http://192.168.0.16:4040/environment/` I can see my jar was added with an entry under **Classpath Entries**:

```
spark://192.168.0.16:60376/jars/lsa.jar
```

But when I try to import a class from the JAR I get:

```
<console>:25: error: object cloudera is not a member of package com
          import com.cloudera.datascience.lsa._
                 ^
```

Does anyone have an idea about what I am missing ?

**Edit**: I also tried to add the JAR via the `spark-defaults.conf`:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /Users/.../lsa.jar
```

but no luck.
I can see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) the doc says:

> Instead, please set this through the --driver-class-path command line option or in your default properties file.

I don't know where to pass this option, should I do it for the master only or for each slave ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like you're mixing up *runtime* dependencies and *compile time* dependencies. What you've added here is a compilation error. If the package isn't available at compile time, you can't reference it like that in your source code.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Would you please see my edit ? can you please tell where is the best practice for adding compile dependencies ? Thanks

Comment: You need to add the JAR as a dependency in your IDE/REPL.

Comment: Thanks so much, I ended up using org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop#require()   and it works

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov excuse me Yuval, this is a little late, but do you know about an alternative of `org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop#require()` in Spark 1.6 ? (It's new in Spark 2.0 I think)