# Error when importing package in spark-shell

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark

Sorry for this question that seems to be asked from time to time. I have read the answers i've seen but as i'm new to scala, i may have not understood them.

I have a build .jar i'd like to use in spark-shell so i launch the shell kike this :

```
$ spark-shell --driver-memory 1g --jars lsa.jar
```

Everything seems to be OK :

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/10/15 16:57:59 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/10/15 16:57:59 WARN Utils: Your hostname, jice-H81M-HD3 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.0.11 instead (on interface enp3s0)
17/10/15 16:57:59 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
17/10/15 16:58:04 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.0.11:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1508079480365).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_144)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

But when I try to use it, ihave an error :

```
scala> import com.cloudera.datascience.lsa._
<console>:23: error: object cloudera is not a member of package com
       import com.cloudera
              ^
```

I have seen here : [Apache Spark not recognising import from external Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810119/apache-spark-not-recognising-import-from-external-jar) a reference to org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop#require() but i can't figure out how to use this.

Do someone can give me a clue ?

Thanks

PS. result of jar -tvf lsa.jar | grep lsa

```
     0 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/
  2485 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$com$cloudera$datascience$lsa$ParseWikipedia$$merge$1$1.class
  2476 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$8$$anonfun$10.class
  3926 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$topDocsInTopConcepts$1.class
  1307 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$trimLeastFrequent$1.class
  1391 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$7.class
  2250 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$saveDocFreqs$2.class
  1283 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$13.class
  2071 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$topTermsInTopConcepts$1$$anonfun$apply$6.class
  1344 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$row$3.class
  1442 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$rowsNormalized$2$$anonfun$3.class
  1842 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$documentFrequencies$2.class
  1373 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$main$2$$anonfun$apply$3.class
  2816 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$rowsNormalized$2.class
  1261 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$10.class
  1752 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$2.class
  2702 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$multiplyByDiagonalMatrix$2.class
  1721 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$multiplyByDiagonalMatrix$2$$anonfun$1.class
  1557 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$5.class
  1351 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$5.class
  1474 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$main$1.class
  1273 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$topTermsForTerm$1.class
  2317 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$5.class
  1841 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$documentFrequencies$1.class
 15390 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$.class
  2897 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$rowsNormalized$1.class
  3454 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$8.class
  1300 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$11.class
  1668 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$rowsNormalized$1$$anonfun$2.class
  1312 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$saveDocFreqs$1.class
  1877 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$inverseDocumentFrequencies$1.class
  1371 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$12.class
  1152 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$4.class
  1497 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$com$cloudera$datascience$lsa$ParseWikipedia$$comb$1$1.class
  3952 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$topTermsInTopConcepts$1.class
  2241 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$plainTextToLemmas$1.class
  1332 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$14.class
  1373 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$main$2$$anonfun$apply$4.class
  1365 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$12.class
  2500 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$plainTextToLemmas$1$$anonfun$apply$4.class
  1416 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$rowsNormalized$2$$anonfun$apply$2.class
 10049 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA.class
  1401 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$11.class
  1491 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$topDocsForDoc$1.class
  1726 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$printIdWeights$1.class
  1331 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$1.class
  2141 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$8$$anonfun$9.class
  2055 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$topDocsInTopConcepts$1$$anonfun$apply$7.class
  2678 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$main$2.class
  2093 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$6.class
  1742 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$rowsNormalized$1$$anonfun$apply$1.class
  1214 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$1.class
  1430 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$com$cloudera$datascience$lsa$ParseWikipedia$$comb$1$2$$anonfun$apply$3.class
  1389 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$termDocumentMatrix$1.class
  1363 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$13.class
  1839 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$multiplyByDiagonalMatrix$1.class
  2678 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.class
  1439 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$com$cloudera$datascience$lsa$ParseWikipedia$$merge$1$1$$anonfun$apply$2.class
  1414 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$row$2.class
  1399 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$readFile$1.class
  1320 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$row$1.class
  1562 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$6.class
 20269 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$.class
  2759 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$com$cloudera$datascience$lsa$ParseWikipedia$$comb$1$2.class
  1651 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$topDocsInTopConcepts$1$$anonfun$9.class
  1616 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/RunLSA$$anonfun$topTermsInTopConcepts$1$$anonfun$8.class
  7015 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia.class
  1562 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$7.class
  1422 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 com/cloudera/datascience/lsa/ParseWikipedia$$anonfun$4.class
     0 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 META-INF/maven/com.cloudera.datascience/lsa/
  2152 Mon Mar 16 12:55:28 CET 2015 META-INF/maven/com.cloudera.datascience/lsa/pom.xml
   113 Sun Oct 15 16:45:50 CEST 2017 META-INF/maven/com.cloudera.datascience/lsa/pom.properties
```

Comment: did you try with full path to the jar?

Comment: Can you do `jar -tvf lsa.jar | grep lsa` and paste the output to your question?  You would've gotten `FileNotFoundException` if the jar had not been found and I assume you did not see the exception, didn't you?

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that this evening. The jar has very probably been found because I tested a lauch with spark-shell --jars option pointing a bad path and I had the exception which I don't have when the path is correct.

Comment: I just tried the full path but it gives same result.

Comment: Can you change `--jars` to `--driver-class-path` and see if that works? Could you also start `spark-shell --jars lsa.jar` and open http://localhost:4040 and take a screenshot of Environment tab with Classpath Entries? It'd be helpful to see the entire Environment tab so take as many screenshots as possible.  Edit your question to add the screenshots.

Comment: With --driver-class-path instead of --jars, it works. I'll have to look at the doc to understand the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With --driver-class-path instead of --jars, it works